# Jquery-ui slider returning a 'cannot read property "nodeName" of null'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, typeerror

I have a javascript function which is returning the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null`. After having a bit of a look around, I can't really find anything relevant to why this would be happening as I do not have any form validation at all. 
 
The weird thing is that it is rendering fine when I load it regularly in a browser, however it needs to be put into a cms. I'm using weebly, and it loads fine one the preview once the html is inputed initially but when published returns the error.

Any ideas to what would be causing this? This is the first time I've encountered this error.

My function is set up to a jquery-ui slider movement action, which is set up to move another hidden slider, which is then set up to change the text on screen.

```
    $(function() {
$('#slider').slider({
    disabled: true,
    range: 'min',
    value: 2013,
    min: 1960,
    max: 2013,
    animate: true,

    change: function (event, ui) { //I am getting the error on this line

        $('#header').text('Year: ' + ui.value);

        xA = ui.value;
        //console.log(xA);

        slider2.setState({'highValue': ui.value});
        slider2.draw();

        setChartView();

    }
}); 
});
```

Comment: So this code is working fine as it is, but throwing error when you put it in some other environment..?